# Is the intrinsic parity the only contribution to parity for single-particle systems?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, photons, angular-momentum, parity

In the book [A Introductory Course Of Particle Physics](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=VYTSBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA167&lpg=PA167&dq=For%20single-particle%20systems,%20intrinsic%20parity%20is%20the%20only%20contribution%20to%20parity.%20For%20multi-particle%20systems,%20however,%20there%20are%20other%20contributions.%20We%20elaborate%20these%20contributions%20in%20case%20of%20a%20two-particle%20system.&source=bl&ots=TVK3xpsw84&sig=zAg3503PRxCt7TDeG9J5tnsHwik&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwimuODe-vLbAhXLo48KHe1QAh0Q6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=For%20single-particle%20systems%2C%20intrinsic%20parity%20is%20the%20only%20contribution%20to%20parity.%20For%20multi-particle%20systems%2C%20however%2C%20there%20are%20other%20contributions.%20We%20elaborate%20these%20contributions%20in%20case%20of%20a%20two-particle%20system.&f=false) by Palash B. Pal, the author claims the following (on page 167, section 6.4.3)

> *For single-particle systems, intrinsic parity is the only contribution to parity.* For multi-particle systems, however, there are other contributions.

However, in addition to intrinsic parity coming from spin, orbital parity can arise for single-particle states if it carries an orbital angular momentum such as photons. See the questions below

1. [What is the orbital angular momentum (OAM) of individual photons?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/99016/what-is-the-orbital-angular-momentum-oam-of-individual-photons)
2. [Does orbital angular momentum has no meaning for single photons?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/210519/does-orbital-angular-mometum-has-no-meaning-for-single-photons)

*Is it true that for single-particle systems, intrinsic parity is the only contribution to parity?*